# How to sort an array of structures based on a field in the structures? (in C)

Tags: c, sorting, selection-sort

I have a program that stores a variety of information about 10 universities as structures in an array. I have a function named 'inputData' that loads the information of the universities into the array by converting them to structures. I am trying to write a function that will sort the universities by tuition (from highest to lowest). I tried to use selection sort to do this, but I keep running into an error somewhere down the line.

This is the structure:

---

```
struct University
{
    char name[50];
    char city[20];
    char state[3];
    int rank;
    int tuition;
};
```

This is the function to convert info to a structure:

```
struct University inputData(char Name[50], char City[20], char State[3], int Rank, int Tuition){
    struct University uni;
    strcpy(uni.name, Name);
    strcpy(uni.city, City);
    strcpy(uni.state, State);
    uni.rank=Rank;
    uni.tuition=Tuition;
    return uni;
};
```

Then I created a structure array and added all the info:

```
struct University university[10];
university[0]= inputData("Princeton University", "Princeton", "NJ", 1, 45320);
university[1]= inputData("University of Virginia", "Charlottesville", "VA", 24, 52040);
university[2]= inputData("Boston College", "Chestnut Hill", "MA", 31, 51296);
university[3]= inputData("Georgia Institute of Technology", "Atlanta", "GA", 34, 32404);
university[4]= inputData("Lehigh University", "Bethlehem", "PA", 44, 48320);
university[5]= inputData("University of Chicago", "Chicago", "IL", 3, 52491);
university[6]= inputData("Duke University", "Durham", "NC", 8, 51265);
university[7]= inputData("University of Georgia", "Athens", "GA", 56, 29844);
university[8]= inputData("University of Denver", "Denver", "CO", 86, 46362);
university[9]= inputData("Loyola University Chicago", "Chicago", "IL", 99, 26270);
```

I'm trying to sort using this function (which uses selection sort):

```
void printSortedUniversity(struct University* list){
    int i, j, max_idx; 
  
      for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
    { 
        max_idx = i; 
        for (j = i+1; j < 10; j++) 
          if (list[j].tuition > list[max_idx].tuition) 
            max_idx = j; 
  
        swap(&list[max_idx], &list[i]); 
    } 
    
    for (i=0; i<10; i++){
        printInfo(list[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
};
```

And this is the swap function:

```
void swap(int *x, int *y) 
{ 
    int temp = *x; 
    *x = *y; 
    *y = temp; 
}
```

I keep getting:

Name: Univceton University      City: Princeton         State: NJ       Rank: 1    Tuition: 45320
Name: Prinersity of Virginia    City: Charlottesville   State: VA       Rank: 24    Tuition: 52040
Name: Univon College    City: Chestnut Hill     State: MA       Rank: 31    Tuition: 51296
Name: Bostgia Institute of Technology   City: Atlanta   State: GA       Rank: 34    Tuition: 32404
Name: Georgh University         City: Bethlehem         State: PA       Rank: 44    Tuition: 48320
Name: Lehiersity of Chicago     City: Chicago   State: IL       Rank: 3    Tuition: 52491
Name: Duke University   City: Durham    State: NC       Rank: 8    Tuition: 51265
Name: University of Georgia     City: Athens    State: GA       Rank: 56    Tuition: 29844
Name: University of Denver      City: Denver    State: CO       Rank: 86    Tuition: 46362
Name: Loyola University Chicago         City: Chicago   State: IL       Rank: 99    Tuition: 26270

I don't understand why the names get corrupted and why the sort doesn't work? I think it's because the modified list isn't being stored anywhere but I have no idea how to fix this.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: Do you *need* to write your own sort or can you just use `qsort`?

Comment: This code *assumes* you have a fixed number of entries. *Always* use an argument to convey *exactly* what is going on.

Comment: Tip: Declare your iterator variables inside the scope in which they're used. Like `for (int i = 0; ...)` helps keep things contained.

Comment: @kashmafia Why are you putting a `;` at the end of the block of `inputData()` function and `printSortedUniversity()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [David Cullen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3657941/david-cullen) wrote about the `swap()` function in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65101279/12180605), the `swap()` function to interchange structures according to `tuition` would be:

```
void swap(struct University *x, struct University *y) 
{ 
    struct University temp = *x; 
    *x = *y; 
    *y = temp; 
}
```

and your `printSortedUniversity()` function should be like this:

```
void printSortedUniversity(struct University* list){
    int i, j, max_idx;

      for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        max_idx = i;
        for (j = i+1; j < 10; j++)
            if (list[j].tuition > list[max_idx].tuition)
                max_idx = j;
        if(i != max_idx)
            swap(&list[max_idx], &list[i]);
    }

    for (i=0; i<10; i++){
        printInfo(list[i]);
        // printf("%d\n",list[i].tuition);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you miss some {} or your indention is wrong?

Comment: @Surt Sorry, It is the indention.

Answer (score 2):

You swap function should be

```c
void swap(struct University *x, struct University *y) 
{ 
    struct University temp = *x; 
    *x = *y; 
    *y = temp; 
}
```

This gives the expected output:

```
Name: University of Chicago City: Chicago Rank: 3 Tuition: 52491
Name: University of Virginia City: Charlottesville Rank: 24 Tuition: 52040
Name: Boston College City: Chestnut Hill Rank: 31 Tuition: 51296
Name: Duke University City: Durham Rank: 8 Tuition: 51265
Name: Lehigh University City: Bethlehem Rank: 44 Tuition: 48320
Name: University of Denver City: Denver Rank: 86 Tuition: 46362
Name: Princeton University City: Princeton Rank: 1 Tuition: 45320
Name: Georgia Institute of Technology City: Atlanta Rank: 34 Tuition: 32404
Name: University of Georgia City: Athens Rank: 56 Tuition: 29844
Name: Loyola University Chicago City: Chicago Rank: 99 Tuition: 26270
```

**Note**

This is an extremely inefficient sort. No one would do this in production code.

Comment: Selection sort at least have one positive, the low number of swaps.

Comment: It would be cheaper to swap pointers. Copying the whole struct is the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

Used this swap function:

```
void swap(struct University *p, struct University *q)  //function to swap list items
{ 
    struct University hold = *p; 
    *p = *q; 
    *q = hold; 
}
```

And I didn't change the printSortedUniversity function:

void printSortedUniversity(struct University* list){
int i, j, max_idx;

```
  for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
{ 
    max_idx = i; 
    for (j = i+1; j < 10; j++) 
      if (list[j].tuition > list[max_idx].tuition) 
        max_idx = j; 

    swap(&list[max_idx], &list[i]); 
} 

for (i=0; i<10; i++){
    printInfo(list[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

};

Comment: Now you just need to accept one of the answers.